# AWS EC2 - Will there be a network/connection failure while changing Elastic IP on the fly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

If we dissociate the Elastic IP from a running EC2 instance and associate a new address while the processes in the instance are communicating to the internet, will there be an error in the existing connection?

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is yes, but you can always test on another EC2 instance: cost $5 + 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If any application is consuming your services, they may become unusable. However new IP will accessible soon after assigning it.